# using geth - retrieved ancestor is invalid

Tags: go-ethereum

I've recently started receiving the error "retrieved ancestor is invalid" when trying to sync my geth node with testnet using `geth --rpcapi personal,db,db,eth,net,web3 --rpc --testnet`. The sync runs great for a while (my last attempt synced up to block 207998), but this error pops up and nothing else will sync. I have upgraded my geth to 1.7.2-stable and have cleared my testnet chaindata twice, but I'm still having this issue. Any suggestions? I'm at a bit of a loss.

Comment: I suggest you to use `networkdid 4` the testenet `ropsten` was under attack.

Comment: This did not work. It got to here: 
INFO [10-26|13:48:18] Imported new state entries               count=0    elapsed=736.671µs processed=1130666 pending=1     retry=1   duplicate=0 unexpected=384

And stayed there for about 20 minutes before I shut it down.

Comment: Maybe it's because you are trying to mine in a different network of your local chain, in that case you should add a different chain path, like: `geth --fast --rpcapi personal,db,db,eth,net,web3 --rpc --datadir="rinkeby" --networkid 4`. Which will create a new directory in the local of the command with the name of the network 4. Also that command use `--fast` to download  
 to not download the entire blockchain.

Comment: Nope, still an issue. I even deleted my whole "Ethereum" directory and had geth rebuild it. I'm going to move on to something else. I have better things to do with my time. Thanks, though!